# example to use flatmap in futures

Tags: scala

I am unable to understand how to use flatMap in Future. 'For'looks fine.

```
object ConcurrencyExample extends App {
val gpf= Future {gpf operations}
val ccf = Future{ccf operations}

//how can I convert this for to flatMap?
val atbf = for {g <- gpf
c <- ccf }  yield {atbf operations}

Await.result(atbf,1000 millis )
 }
```

Comment: `gpf.flatMap { _ => ccf }.map { _ => atbf }`

Answer (score 1):

for comprehension can be de-sugared into `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`.

here is how you can do it.

```
for {
  foo <- FooF
  bar <- BarF(foo)
  baz <- BazF if bar > 0
  bow <- BowF(baz)
} yield (baz + 1)
```

The above thing can be converted to

```
FooF.flatMap { foo => //inner bindings become flatMap
  BarF(foo).flatMap { bar =>
    BazF.filter { baz => baz > 0 } //guards become filter 
    .flatMap { baz => 
      BowF(baz)
    }.map { baz => baz + 1 } // yield becomes map
  }
}
```

So your for-comprehension becomes

```
gpf.flatMap { _ => ccf }.map { _ => atbf }
```